# Why does my transition animation have a hitch when it is closing a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a card that expands to show more content when you click on the arrow on the bottom right. I noticed that if I hit the arrow to close the extra content, there is a slight hitch before it closes.

It looks like it first takes out the padding, then closes the entire div. Is there any way to make this animation smooth without having the choppy animation?

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rohithdm/55L52yww/62/)

JavaScript for the toggling of the class.

```
$('.remove-text').click(function() {
        var el = event.target.parentElement;
        console.log(el);
        console.log(event.target);
        $(el).closest('.card').toggleClass('collapsed');
        if (  $( event.target).css( "transform" ) == 'none' ){
            $(event.target).css("transform","rotate(180deg)");
        } else {
            $(event.target).css("transform","" );
        }
    })
```

Comment: its because you are trying animate `max-height`. You really can't animate a dynamic height with a css `transition`. You will have to animate to static height (like [this JSFiddle of your demo](https://jsfiddle.net/55L52yww/63/)) or do your height animation in javascript like what jQuery's `.slideToggle` does... or just use `.slideToggle`.

Comment: @zgood the `max-height` trick is having a bad effect, but it's the padding that RP12 is removing that's causing the jump

Comment: @SandyGifford Yes thank you, both of you were correct. What ended up working was removing the pattern as well as changing the max height to a fixed height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're removing padding without adding a transition - this gives the effect of jumping (or as you say, the "hitch") before continuing the animation.  Below I've added `padding 0.5s` to the transition declaration.

2 side notes:

1) you don't need the transition definition on your `.collapsed .content` block - that property is already inherited from `.content`

2) you may notice a delay before the animation happens - this is a side effect of the `max-height` trick you're using.  Lower the max height (risks cutting off content) or try a different [`transition-animation-function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function)

```js
$(".remove-text").click(function() {
  var el = event.target.parentElement;
  $(el).closest(".card").toggleClass("collapsed");
  
  if ($(event.target).css("transform") == "none") {
    $(event.target).css("transform", "rotate(180deg)");
  } else {
    $(event.target).css("transform", "");
  }
});
```

```css
.dashboard-setup-thumb {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.20);
    box-shadow: 1px 0 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.20);
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    height: 98px;
    width: 98px;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    position: relative;
}

.display-inline {
    display: inline-block;
}

.remove-text{
    bottom: 0.5rem;
    right: 0.5rem;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    right: 0.1rem;
}

.checkbox-position {
    top: 0.8rem;
    right: 0rem;
    position:absolute;
}

#job-setup-qty {
    margin-left: 15%;
    padding: 0rem
}

.job-setup-checkbox {
    top: 0.8rem;
    right: 0rem;
    position:absolute;
}

.card-content-width {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
}

.collapsed .content{
    max-height: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.content {
    overflow:hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    max-height: 500px;
    transition: max-height 0.5s, padding 0.5s;
}

.arrow-change {
    color: $link;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 42%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 42%;
    -o-transform-origin: 50% 42%;
    transform-origin: 50% 42%;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;
}

.more-horiz-job {
    color: $link;
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.remove-text {
    display: flex;
}

.more-horiz-col{
    margin-left: 5px !important;
    margin-right: 5px !important;
}

.view-edit-col {
    margin-left: 5px !important;
}

.card {
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.select-wrapper-qty {
    margin-left: -10px;
}

.thumbnail-icon {
    position: absolute;
    left: 7px;
    top: 7px;
    height: 2.5rem;
    width: 2.5rem;
}

.qty-div {
    margin-bottom: 0.7em;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">

<div class="row m-b-0">
        <div class="col s12 m12 l12 p-0">
            <div class="card hoverable collapsed">
                <div class="card-content card-content-width p-l-0 p-b-0 p-t-0 row m-b-0">
                    <div class="col s4 m4 l4 dashboard-setup-thumb display-inline" style="background-image:url({{imageSrc instruction.thumbnail}});">
                        <i class="dm-icons icon-dash-print thumbnail-icon"></i>
                        <div class="material-yellow"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s5 m6 l6 display-inline m-t-20">
                        <h4 class="row m-b-0 m-t-0 truncfunc truncate left-align tooltipped" data-position="top" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="{{instruction.name}}"></h4>
                        
                            <h5 class="row m-b-10 m-t-5 truncate status-instruction">Setup for printing.</h5>
                        
                            <div class="row m-b-0 align-down {{#unless isSelected}}hide{{/unless}}">
                                <div class="col s3 m3 l6 p-0 align-down">
                                    <div class="p-0 qty-div">QTY</div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="job-setup-qty" class="js-job-number input-field col s3 m4 l4 m-b-0">
                                  
                                    <label></label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                     
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s3 m3 l1">
                        <form class="display-inline job-setup-checkbox"><p>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in"   {{isChecked}} id="{{pageTitle}}_{{instruction._id}}"  />
                            <label class="p-l-26" for="{{pageTitle}}_{{instruction._id}}"></label>
                        </p>
                        </form>
                        <div class="display-inline remove-text" href="#">
                            <i class="material-icons medium-3-rem arrow-change">expand_more</i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content dm-gray light">
                    <div class="col s1 m1 l1 more-horiz-col">
                        <i class="material-icons medium-3-rem more-horiz-job">more_horiz</i></div>
                    <div class="col s4 m4 l4 view-edit-col">
                        <div class="label dis-inline view-edit">View/Edit</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s4 m4 l4 p-r-2">
                        <div class="dis-inline right delete-div label">DELETE<i class="material-icons medium-3-rem  dis-inline">delete</i></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Went ahead and removed the max height and just used a fixed height. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Padding is causing the issue. You can remove padding from that element and add margin to one of its child to have the same spacing.

```
.content {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    /* padding-top: 10px; */
    /* padding-bottom: 10px; */
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    /* padding-top: 4px; */
    /* padding-bottom: 4px; */
    max-height: 500px;
    transition: max-height 0.5s;
}
.more-horiz-col{
  margin: 20px 0px;
}
```

Comment: this should be the answer.